# any suggestions on how to speed up mysql delete

Tags: mysql, database, performance, sql-delete

I'm trying to run this delete and I don't think it will ever finish. Any suggestions on how to increase performance would be appreciated. Thx

```
delete CCLE.table1
from CCLE.table1  
join CCLE.table1 table2 
on CCLE.table1.cor_estimate = table2.cor_estimate 
and CCLE.table1.g1_gene_symbol = table2.g2_gene_symbol 
and CCLE.table1.g2_gene_symbol = table2.g1_gene_symbol 
and CCLE.table1.g1_ncbi_gene_id < CCLE.table1.g2_ncbi_gene_id;
```

Comment: 1 - is it working | 2 - How long does it takes | 3 - what are your expectations?

Comment: it works but trying on a table with 150 million rows and it never finishes. wondering if there is a way to rewrite to improve performance.

Comment: are ur tables well indexed ? Innodb or myisam ?

Comment: yes indexed on the search columns though EXPLAIN shows that the keys are not used. Innodb

Comment: We can't see that

Comment: I don't see the point of the JOIN here. Surely the RH term in the `<` condition should use `table2`?

Comment: 1 - Is it a query you need to apply everyday/several times or is that just a temporary command you need to use ? | 2 - Why there is no WHERE condition ?

Comment: Looks like you have gene pairs stored twice and want to get rid of one of the redundant rows?

Answer (score 1):

Composite index:

```
INDEX(cor_estimate, g1_gene_symbol, g2_gene_symbol, g1_ncbi_gene_id)
```

Even that may not speed it up "enough".  Then, I would consider doing it in "chunks", perhaps as discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

You might consider sorting (via `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`) the two gene_symbols before storing them.  That way, they are in a canonical order, and maybe the query is obviated.